# How do I find mass equivalence of a photon?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

> The problem has a flame emitting a wavelength of $589\ \mathrm{nm}$, and asks for the mass of one photon of that wavelength. It tells me that $1\ \mathrm J = 1\ \frac{\mathrm{kg\cdot m^2}}{\mathrm s^2}$.

I converted to $\mathrm J$ using $E=\frac{h\cdot c}{\lambda}$. I'm not quite sure what to do past that. I have $3.36\cdot 10^{-19}\mathrm J$. I know the answer is supposed to be $3.75\cdot 10^{-34}$.

Comment: Then the answer should be 3.75x10^-36 not to the -34. If that is what the book answer was then I don't know how they got that.

Comment: A  photon's rest mass is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E = \frac{h\cdot c}{\lambda}$$

$$1\ \mathrm J = 6.24150934 \times 10^{18}\ \mathrm{eV}$$

then you have 
$$E = mc^2 = \frac{h\cdot c}{\lambda}$$

Comment: A photon doesnt have rest mass.

Comment: However, what is asked here is the total mass including that imparted by the motion of the photon. Actually a proton at rest makes no sense anyway. We always observe them moving at the speed of light.

Comment: What do you mean by " the total mass including that imparted by the motion of the photon"?

Comment: @JunSeo-He I think he's referring to "dynamic/relativistic mass", but you probably already know that. What exactly that means is another story, and somebody more learned than I should handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply calculate the energy: $E=h\nu$

Then solve for momentum: $p=E/c$

Then divide by the speed of light: $p=mv$ or $m=p/v$

With the speed of light for $v$ so:  $m=p/c$

Comment: A photon doesnt have rest mass.

Comment: However, what is asked here is the total mass including that imparted by the motion of the photon. Actually a proton at rest makes no sense anyway. We always observe them moving at the speed of light.

Comment: What do you mean by " the total mass including that imparted by the motion of the photon"?